# How to Boost an AC Voltage signal from 18 Vpp to 30Vpp range

Tags: amplifier, circuit-design

I am interested in creating a portable diagnostic tool, and as such would like to passively (no wall plug) amplify the 18Vpp sine wave signal that I have (4-7 kHz range) to about 30 Vpp to adequately power a disc style PZT on my device. I have searched extensively and have not been able to come up with a good solution thus far. Alternative ideas require using some sort of MOSFET circuit still requiring a larger external voltage. This is not ideal, since I was hoping to use the setup and signal I have right now to power my device. Thanks.

Comment: If you also had an inverted form of that 18Vp-p signal available, you could simply bridge drive the piezo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the frequency was fixed, you could have used a LC resonant tank, but frequency is variable.

So, if you want to passively increase voltage on a signal, pretty much the only solution you have is a transformer.

Another solution would be to use switching converters to get higher DC voltages, and power your signal amplifier from these.

Both have merits in terms of size, weight, efficiency and cost.

Comment: Thanks for your response. If I were to determine that on the whole, 6500Hz works well for my devices, how could I go about using the resonant tank? Determine a capacitor and inductor pair which has a resonant frequency of 6500, and then?

Comment: It's a piezo, right? It behaves more or less like a cap, so you can build a series resonant LC tank around it. Make sure Q isn't too high (or it will be too selective in frequency) nor too low (not enough amplification). You could also use a more powerful transducer, or a more sensitive receiver, etc...

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to find a suitable transformer, maybe with an amorphous core. Start to compute anything at lowest possible frequency and maximum voltage amplitude, because the flux will be largest at low frequency. Then, if you put a signal with higher frequency or smaller amplitude, anything will still work normally.

Answer (score 1):

A normal audio transformer (20 Hz to 20 kHz) will be fine as long as it it properly derated.  $$V_1 \cdot f_1 = V_2\cdot f_2$$

This means that you can maybe use a 15 V p-p to 9 V p-p audio transformer or even something like a 5 V p-p to 3 V p-p transformer.